# AEM Maven convert to i18n text in dialog value of text

Tags: java, maven, dialog, aem

I have this code below

```
<disclaimer
jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/heading"
level="3"
text="Convert to i18n"/>
```

I am having this in dialog box and I want to convert the text part to i18n. I know how to convert in html like :

```
<a href="#" title="" data-sly-text="${'Convert to i18n' @ i18n}">もっと見る</a>
```

FYI:

I have an i18n json file with the corresponding value.

I cant seem to make it work in dialog.

Is this possible?
Suggestions are much appreciated.

> Update:

I found [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/heading/index.html)

But I cant understand if this will solve my issue on how to automatically put i18n conversion on dialog text heading

Comment: Not sure if I understood completely what you're aiming for but I guess you could try something along the lines described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VNsqQlMuD0). I have never used it though to internationalize the 'text' value.

Comment: i have look at the video and it looks like that is what i wanted. let me check it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sightly when you use i18n the locale is derived from the page, but in case of Dialogs and Authoring UI the locale is derived from the selected UI language for the current author, just change the language in user properties.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It kind-of works OOTB based on the selected user language. You just need to do two things:

1. Add the i18 key and translations to your language.json file, e.g. /apps/demo/i18n/en.json

```
{
"com.test.aem.prefix.label": "Some prefix text"
}
```

2. In your dialog definition use the i18n key as fieldLabel

```
<prefix-text
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/textfield"
    fieldLabel="com.test.aem.prefix.label"
    name="./prefixText" />
```